# Slow query performance and Inner join

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I believe my slow query is due to an inner join I'm trying to perform.
Instead of:

```
SELECT ot.email, mt.old_email, mt.new_email
  FROM dbo.MainTable AS mt
  INNER JOIN dbo.OtherTable AS ot ON ot.email = mt.old_email
                                  OR ot.email = mt.new_email
```

What would be a more efficient join to run this? Using an Union all statement seems tedious, but maybe I'm wrong.
I also tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT ot.email, mt.old_email, mt.new_email
  FROM dbo.MainTable AS mt
  INNER JOIN dbo.OtherTable AS ot ON ot.email = (case  when mt.old_email !=ot.email THEN mt.new_email)
```

Comment: please read the section about performance questions and also other prts of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: The UNION is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure this is Snowflake and not MS SQL Server?

Regardless, it’s not an efficient query wise to OR the only join condition.  I would write as:

```
SELECT ot.email, mt.old_email, mt.new_email
  FROM dbo.MainTable mt, 
       dbo.OtherTable ot
  Where  ot.email = mt.old_email 
Union
SELECT ot.email, mt.old_email, mt.new_email
  FROM dbo.MainTable  mt,
       dbo.OtherTable ot 
  Where ot.email = mt.new_email;
```

Comment: your use of UNION to simplify the query is correct, but not sure why you have resorted to non-ansi joins?

Comment: Because I’m typing on my cell phone and ANSI is too verbose 

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your "data" different blocks of SQL will give different results:

for example I made some data:

```
with MainTable(old_email,new_email) as (
    select * from values
        ('abc','East'),
        ('abc','East')
), OtherTable(email) as (
    select * from values
        ('abc'),
        ('East')
)
```

your SQL:

```
SELECT 
    ot.email
    ,mt.old_email
    ,mt.new_email
  FROM MainTable AS mt
  JOIN OtherTable AS ot
    ON ot.email = mt.old_email
        OR ot.email = mt.new_email
```

gives:

| EMAIL | OLD_EMAIL | NEW_EMAIL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | abc | East |
| East | abc | East |
| abc | abc | East |
| East | abc | East |

which makes sense to me.

Jim's SQL gives:

```
SELECT ot.email, mt.old_email, mt.new_email
  FROM MainTable mt, 
       OtherTable ot
  Where  ot.email = mt.old_email 
Union
SELECT ot.email, mt.old_email, mt.new_email
  FROM MainTable  mt,
       OtherTable ot 
  Where ot.email = mt.new_email;
```

| EMAIL | OLD_EMAIL | NEW_EMAIL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | abc | East |
| East | abc | East |

I would normal say split the logic up, to discreate branches of the OR and use a UNION ALL to avoid the costly deduplication step on a naked UNION.

which for this data changing Jim's UNION to a UNION ALL appears to work:

```
SELECT ot.email, mt.old_email, mt.new_email
  FROM MainTable mt, 
       OtherTable ot
  Where  ot.email = mt.old_email 
Union ALL
SELECT ot.email, mt.old_email, mt.new_email
  FROM MainTable  mt,
       OtherTable ot 
  Where ot.email = mt.new_email;
```

but really we should split it to three blocks, both A & B, just A, just B and union those:

thus:

```
SELECT ot.email, mt.old_email, mt.new_email
FROM MainTable mt
JOIN OtherTable ot
    ON  ot.email = mt.old_email AND ot.email = mt.new_email
Union ALL
SELECT ot.email, mt.old_email, mt.new_email
FROM MainTable mt
JOIN OtherTable ot
    ON  ot.email = mt.old_email AND ot.email <> mt.new_email
UNION ALL
SELECT ot.email, mt.old_email, mt.new_email
FROM MainTable mt
JOIN OtherTable ot
    ON  ot.email <> mt.old_email AND ot.email = mt.new_email;
```

gives:

| EMAIL | OLD_EMAIL | NEW_EMAIL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | abc | East |
| abc | abc | East |
| East | abc | East |
| East | abc | East |

If you can avoid string comparisons and use number's) that should give you a small speed improvement also, but might require processing that moves the cost elsewhere in you processing stack.

Comment: I left the Union intentionally without the All as I assumed the result set was intended to be absent of duplicates, but you’re correct in that the original query would have produced dupes in the result, and a union all would’ve delivered the equivalent results.

Comment: My main point is the it impossible to know the fastest way to “boost” the query without knowing the nature if the data. Aka what assumptions are valid. My code is wrong as the handling of nulls is incorrect.  So yet mire clauses.